# How to add Weld CDI support to a working Jetty application?

Tags: java, gradle, jetty, cdi, weld

I am currently using Jetty 9 for deploying my WAR files.

For dependency management, I'm using Gradle; my `build.gradle` file looks as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    /**
     * Jersey.
     */
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.22.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.22.1'
    /**
     * Weld CDI.
     */
    compile 'org.jboss.weld.servlet:weld-servlet-core:2.3.2.Final'

    /**
     * JUnit.
     */
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

My `web.xml` looks as follows:

```xml
<web-app version="3.0">
<display-name>Example Api</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RESTful Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.api</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RESTful Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

However, when I try to deploy, I get the following stack trace:

```
[2015-12-16 09:13:33,315] Artifact Gradle : api : api.war: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
Dec 16, 2015 9:13:36 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener onStartup
INFO: WELD-ENV-001008: Initialize Weld using ServletContainerInitializer
Dec 16, 2015 9:13:36 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900: 2.3.2 (Final)
Dec 16, 2015 9:13:36 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle initialize
INFO: WELD-ENV-000028: Weld initialization skipped - no bean archive found
Dec 16, 2015 9:13:36 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener contextInitialized
INFO: WELD-ENV-001007: Initialize Weld using ServletContextListener
Dec 16, 2015 9:13:36 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle initialize
INFO: WELD-ENV-000028: Weld initialization skipped - no bean archive found
```

Followed by `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton not set for STATIC_INSTANCE => []`.

Can somebody please tell me what needs to be done to get this working?

I am just trying to `@Inject` my dependencies in Jetty, but I only find myself struggling with configuration settings for days on end...

Comment: Are you using [tag:embedded-jetty]? (either your own, or from gradle?) or are you deploying to jetty-distribution?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I'm deploying to a jetty distribution (literally dropping the .war inside $JETTY_HOME/webapps and running `java -jar start.jar`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use Weld/CDI on Jetty Distribution, you'll need to do the following.

> This is partly documented on the Weld/CDI side at [Environments: Jetty](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_jetty)

1. Include the weld jars appropriate for your usage in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your WAR file. (lets call this `mywebapp.war`)
2. Create a `${jetty.base}` directory, and configure it properly.
3. DO NOT EDIT / CHANGE / DELETE / RENAME any content in `${jetty.home}` or `$JETTY_HOME`.  If you are doing this, you are already not using jetty properly.
4. Create a XML Deployable to allow Weld/CDI to see through the Standard Servlet Classloader Isolation with a file called `${jetty.base}/webapps/mywebapp.xml`
5. Copy `mywebapp.war` to `${jetty.base}/webapps/` directory.
6. Start jetty.

Example of `${jetty.base}` setup

```
$ mkdir /path/to/mybase
$ cd /path/to/mybase
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --add-to-start=http,deploy
```

Example of `${jetty.base}/webapps/mywebapp.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/weld-numberguess</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps" default="."/>/mywebapp.war</Set>
  <Call name="prependServerClass">
    <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler</Arg>
  </Call>
  <Call name="prependServerClass">
    <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder</Arg>
  </Call>
  <Call name="prependServerClass">
    <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler</Arg>
  </Call>
  <Call name="prependServerClass">
    <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder</Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step explanation! I've tried to follow it, but now I'm getting the following error:

`2015-12-17 21:14:32.102:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet`

again followed by

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton not set for STATIC_INSTANCE => []`

I've tried looking for the jar containing the JettyJspServlet class, but I can't find the right dependency in www.mvnrepository.com. Do you know where to find it?

Comment: jsp is a different topic, a new / different question please.